# Python - Spectral analysis

Tags: python, list, numpy, fft

Is there a way to display spectral analisys resoult as a number in exact harmonical freqyencys?
I've got raw voltage measurements for a household, so expected power suply is sinusoidal waveform, 300V peak to -300V negative peak with frequency of 50 Hz, and my sampling frequency is 24 kHz.

I've been trying to use numpy fft and numpy fftfreq on this signal to get the spectral analisys, but i dont want to plot it.

I need a list of number with harmonical values in its exact points. For example:
[0 76 0 12 0 12 0]
Meaning that given signal is in 76% 50 Hz sine, 12% 150Hz sine and in 12% 250Hz sine.
First position in a list should be value of 0 Hz, 2nd of 50Hz, 3rd od 100Hz etc. up to 40th position meaning the value of 2k Hz.

Is there a way to do it? Or at least where shuld i seek?

I've been using np.fft and np.fftfreq. Tried to display in in console and to plot it even no this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How many samples did you capture? What result did you get, and in what way is it not giving you the values you want? If you want 50 Hz for the first bin of your FFT you must capture exactly 480 samples at 24 kHz.

Comment: It'd be helpful to get some example data and code. It might be as simple as using [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) in conjunction with `np.fft.fft` and `np.fft.fftshift`. You may need to plot the results a few times to get an idea of what's happening, but after that you can run it without plotting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.